# NETWORKDAYS / Business Days calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Say I want an "IF" formula that checks a cell (a1) with a date indicated then on a different cell (b1) it validates the indicated date on cell A1 that its already pass 3 business days once confirmed cell B1 would indicate as a "Yes" if  not then a "No", is this possible?

tried using the networkdays but that doesn't seem to match up the requirement of inquiry

none yet, that's why I am asking...

a formula should be provided, that's much better.

Comment: The first date to compare is in A1.. in which cell is the 2nd date located? if you don't mind, you shall share the "unsuccessful formula you're tried too. ( :

Comment: So you have tried: `=IF(NETWORKDAYS(A1,TODAY())>2,"YES","NO")`? Like @p._phidot_ I'm equally curious on your current formula.

Comment: Thank you JvdV, your formula did answered my question perfectly. apologies if I did confuse both you, but I am totally a dumb already when it comes to excel formula, unlike before. T-SQL eaten my brain alive. :O

Comment: @PaulNikkolaiArma, kindly accept the given answer if this answers the question to close this question.

Comment: done, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(A1,TODAY())>2,"YES","NO")
```

Also take note that you can include holidays within your function!